# Why this inner HTML table have the width determined by its content? How can I set to the width of its container?

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml, html-table

I am not so into HTML and CSS and I have the following problem. I have the following CSS structure:

```
<!-- REFERENTE TECNICO: -->
<div id="referenteTecnicoTab">
  <table width="800px" class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">
    <thead class="opening">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow.gif"/>
          Ricerca Fatture
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="expanded" style="display: none;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="ricercaFattureContent" class="accordion-pane-content">

            <table width="100%" class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls" >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center; border-left: 0">Ricerca Fatture</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see into the div having **id=ricercaFattureContent** I have a table that contains a **thead** showing the **Ricerca Fatture** text and a **tbody** that show the **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa** example text.

The problem is that this table have the width of the inner text (in this case of the **aaa....aaa** text).

What can I try to do to obtain that this table have the same width of its container?

I am going crazy trying to do it, using FireBug it seems that is is the **tr** inside the **tbody** that have the width determined by its content, this section of the previous code:

```
<table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls" width="100%">
  <thead class="opening active">
  <tbody class="expanded" style="display: block;">
    <tr>
      THE tr TAKE THE WIDTH OF ITS CONTENT
```

So I obtain something like this:

[image]

I want that the table have the width of its container, what can I do?

Tnx

Comment: Have you tried giving #ricercaFattureContent a width value too?

Comment: Ehm, the inner table is inside something with `display:none`, or am I missing something vital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it seems like you have a `width="800px"` as an attribute on the table element, you also have the tbody set to `display: none;`

here's a fiddle with the fixes:
http://jsfiddle.net/ak0ygz2n/

notice that i colored the container orange to display the concept, and set the table width to 100% of the container.